# Show Json Data after pushing Enter instead of Click ob submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view that by clicking on submit button it post Data using Ajax to the Controller. The controller return json result that is messages and I show them on the View. The problem is when I click on Submit button it working fine but when I push Enter after show the Thank you page again it post to the controller method and show a page with json Data as bellow: (I need to make the Enter work as pushing Submit as well)

```
 {"status":"success","message":""}
```

This is my View:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("forgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div>
                <div>Email Address</div>
                <div><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" id="email" class="forgot-password-textbox"></div>
                <div><label id="Message" class="forgot-password-error-message"></label></div>
                <div><input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn-reset-password" onclick="resetPasswordHandler()" class="orange-button forgot-password-button"></div>
            </div>
        }
```

This is my Controller Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("forgotPassword")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordRequest forgotPasswordRequest)
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(forgotPasswordRequest.Email))
                {
                    users = await authenticationService.GetUserByEmailAsync(forgotPasswordRequest.Email);
                    if (users.Any())
                    {
                        if(users.FirstOrDefault().StatusId == 2)
                        {
                            return Json(new { status = "error", message = Constants.MessageStrings.ForgotPasswordDisabledUser });
                        }
                        //New User without creating password
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(users.FirstOrDefault().PasswordHash))
                        {                            
                                return Json(new { status = "error", message = Constants.MessageStrings.ForgotPasswordDisabledUser });
                        }
                        ....
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", Constants.MessageStrings.NoUser);
                        return Json(new { status = "error", message = Constants.MessageStrings.NoUser });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                .......
        return Json(new { status = "error", message = Constants.MessageStrings.RequiredFields });
    }
```

and this is my Ajax to call controller:

```
function resetPasswordHandler() {
var postResult = null;
var data = {
    Email: document.getElementById('email').value
};
var path = "/forgotPassword";

var errorMessage = document.getElementById('Message');

$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: path,
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        postResult = $.parseJSON(result);
        if (postResult.status == "success") {
            $('#forgot').hide();
            $('#forgot-thank-you').show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = postResult.message;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "An error occured";
    }
});
return false;
};


window.onkeydown = function () {
   if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
     resetPasswordHandler();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Delete you `onclick="resetPasswordHandler()"` and use `$('form').submit(function() { ...code inside resetPasswordHandler method here ... });` (use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)). And delete your `window.onkeydown` script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Json(new { status="success",message="what ever your msg"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the click handler from the button, and handle the submit event of the relevant form.

You should give an id for easier targeting

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("forgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "reset-form" }))
```

And simplify your script (*since you are using jQuery*) to

```js
function resetPasswordHandler(event) {
  var postResult = null,
      data = {
        Email: $('#email').val()
      },
      path = "/forgotPassword",
      errorMessage = $('#Message');

  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: path,
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      postResult = $.parseJSON(result);
      if (postResult.status == "success") {
        $('#forgot').hide();
        $('#forgot-thank-you').show();
        return;
      } else {
        errorMessage.html(postResult.message);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      errorMessage.html("An error occured");
    }
  });
  return false;
};

$('#reset-form').on('submit', resetPasswordHandler);
```